# React: Trying to pass an array to a functional component, but it won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

As, the Title says...  I can get the console to echo the array, but It won't render on my navigation bar.

From App.js:

```
unValidatedUserButtons = ["Search", "Login", "Register"];  

render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
          <Header />
          <Topnav buttons={this.unValidatedUserButtons}/>
      </Layout>
    )
}
```

to TopNav:

```
buttonHandlerTnav = (buttonPass) => {
    let newButtons = [...buttonPass];
    this.setState({buttons: newButtons});
    this.setState({needButtons: false});
}

render(){
    if (this.state.needButtons)
    this.buttonHandlerTnav(this.props.buttons);
    return (
        <div className={classes.TopNav}>
                <MenuButton />       
               <AccountButtons 
                buttonPass={this.state.buttons} /> 
        </div>
    );   
}
```

Then to AccountButtons:

```
const buttonHandlerAccount = (newButtons) => { newButtons.map((Button, index)    => {
        return (<button key={index}>{Button}</button>)
    });
}

const accountButtons = (props) => {

    // console.log(props.buttonPass);
    return (
        <div className={classes.AccountButtons}>
        {buttonHandlerAccount(props.buttonPass)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If anyone could help me get my buttons to render, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're storing the buttons in `state` in `TopNav` instead of just passing them further down? Also why are you doing it in render?

Answer (score 0):

`buttonHandlerAccount` is missing a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

```
// Button Handler Account.
const buttonHandlerAccount = (newButtons) => {
  return newButtons.map((Button, index) => <button key={index}>{Button}</button>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a `return` in your functional component. Try this to resolve your problem:

```
const buttonHandlerAccount = (newButtons) => { 
    return newButtons.map((Button, index)    => {
        return (<button key={index}>{Button}</button>)
    });
}
```

Or, the short hand equivalent:

```
const buttonHandlerAccount = (newButtons) => (newButtons.map((Button, index)    => {
        return (<button key={index}>{Button}</button>)
    }))
```